# Model loading fails in Pyinstaller-deployed app

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pyinstaller, yolo

I am trying to use a model.pt deployed through yolov5 and pytorch in opencv.
It works fine when running in Python, but there is a problem when deploying it as an exe and running it.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import torch
from PIL import Image
import sys
# Load YOLOv5 model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='model.pt')   
print("test")
# opencv code.....
```

And my project structure is as follows:

```
- build/
- dist/
- yolov5/
- main.py
- main.spec
- model.pt
```

There is a problem in the part of my code where I load the model.
The following code is the code I originally tried to load the model. When I run it after deployment, I get an error that I can't find the ultralytics module.

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='model.pt')
```

To fix this, I added the corresponding module to the `hiddenimports` in main.spec and tried running it again, but the problem continued, such as not being able to find a file called ultralytics/default.yaml.

---- Edit

My main.spec code is as follows:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('model.pt', '.')],
    hiddenimports=['ultralytics'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
```

After deploying with pyinstaller main.spec and trying to run it in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \dist\main\_internal\ultralytics\cfg\default.yaml'
```

Upon checking the directory of the deployed app, I found that the ultralytics folder does not exist.

Can anyone tell me about this problem?
Thank you.